# Have I missed something with CSS or is DomSanitizer and Renderer2 causing my CSS to not flow or inherit as it should?

Tags: angular, typescript, xss, innerhtml

Background story. I am creating my own Calendar and Angular has safety features built in for the use of innerHTML. I won't lie, I am new so my code is not pretty, sorry. I was following some tutorials and adding things as I went. This is the function building divs into my html using innerHTML. This function is set to a variable right now, which is called in the ngAfterViewInit().

```
divAndClassGenerator(){
    this.htmlContent = '';
    
    for(let x = this.firstDayIndex; x>0; x--){
      this.htmlContent += `<div class="prev-date">${this.prevLastDay - x + 1}</div>`
  }
  
    
    for(let i =1; i<=this.lastDay; i++){
      if(i === new Date().getDate() && this.date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()){
           this.htmlContent += `<div class="today" value="${i}">${i}</div>`;
      } else {
          this.htmlContent += `<div value="${i}">${i}</div>`;
      }
  } 

    for(let j = 1; j<=this.nextDays; j++){
    this.htmlContent += `<div class="next-date" value="${j}">${j}</div>`
  } 
    let safeHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.htmlContent);
    let myElement = this.renderer.selectRootElement('.days');
    this.renderer.setProperty(myElement, 'innerHTML', safeHtml);
    
    return safeHtml;

  }
```

This is my html that innerHTML is being used to access. I feel like I may be going about this in a unnecessary way with the 2 variables.

```
<div class="days" [innerHTML] = "safeInnerHtml">
```

Finally this is part of the CSS that I want accessed my the divs being created.

```
.days {
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    
}

.days div{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin: 0.3rem;
    width: calc(30rem/7);
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.days div:hover:not(.today){
    background-color: #262626;
    border: 0.2rem solid #777;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-date ,
.next-date  {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.today{
    background-color: #7e1616;
}
```

The current build of my page renders the calendar dates but does not use the CSS I have here. It is inheriting bits and pieces from the CSS that occurs before these. The previous CSS are linked to the parent container of the div .days from above. I am not sure why the CSS is not inheriting or flowing like I expect it to.

I have tried so many things the last 2 days I barely remember, most of them involved moving variables, blocks of code, rewriting the DomSanitizer and Renderer2 statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the css you wrote in your component is only encapsulated on this component content , if you want to apply your css to the content you provide with innerHTML , you have to use ng-deep

```html
:host ::ng-deep .days div {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: While it works, it's not particularly idiomatic Angular code.
You might do it something like this in React, but in Angular, it's more idiomatic to set up a data structure representing the dates that you'd like to render, create a component that can render a calendar 'cell', and then have a parent component with a template that iterates over the data structure (e.g. *ngFor), and in the loop, represents each 'cell' with the 'cell' component. That is, use components and the templating system, instead of building innerHTML, selecting an element via the renderer, and using the DomSanitizer.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek  Thank you. Are there any examples you know of that you can point me to? I think I understand, but I would like to see how a working structure would be set up.

Comment: @AshleyForrest maybe start with the basic Angular tutorial at https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes